# How can I create an object which acts as a "contract" for data (e.g an integer) to be placed there later?

Tags: c#

I'm populating an object[] with items of different types - e.g [string, int, DateTime]. Some values depend on data that only becomes available later (in real-time). I would like to create a "contract" for this data in the array, and then later when the data is available, swap out the "contract" object for the actual data. So if it is a Contract, then I can change the Contract to a string later on. *I am using the term "contract" here in a unique way, not necessarily relevant to any other uses of the term that you may be familiar with. I'm open to dropping this term if it becomes confusing, it just helped me conceptualize my use case.*

At first I tried overloading the int cast operator:

```
// Expected types: string, int, DateTime
object[] Item = new object[] { 
    "hello", new Contract<int>(), DateTime.Now()
}

public class Contract<T>
{
    public static implicit operator int(Contract<T> Contract)
    {
        // Here the data would be actually resolved
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, in the client code (in a referenced assembly I have no control over) where `object[] Item` is used, I get the following error: `` expected System.Int32 but found Namespace.Contract `1[System.Int32] ``. Apparently, the client code expects an Int32 value but receives an Int32 boxed inside a Contract, if I understand this error message (I might not).

One way I thought of trying to do this was:

```
// Expected types: string, int, DateTime
object[] Item = new object[] { 
    "hello", new Contract<int>(), DateTime.Now()
}

// Interface to allow creating a List of generics
public interface IContract {}

List<IContract> Contracts = new List<IContract>();

public class Contract<T> : IContract
{
    public Contract()
    {
        Contracts.Add(this);
    }    

    public static implicit operator int(Contract<T> Contract)
    {
        // Here the data would be actually resolved
        return 0;
    }
}

// And later on
foreach (var Contract in Contracts)
{
    Contract = (int)(Contract<int>)Contract;
}
```

But for obvious reasons foreach iteration variables are immutable.

The difficulty is that when the client code comes to evaluate the contents of the array, it expects an integer but finds a boxed value. If it was dynamic, it would still encounter a Contract object rather than the int it expects. I overloaded the int cast operator in hopes that it would perform a cast to the type it expects, but it does not. I really need some way of either a) automatically unboxing the type when the client code evaluates it or b) manually unboxing the type myself just beforehand.

Any ideas on how to proceed? I'm open to changing to a different pattern entirely. The thought of initializing the object[] without the correct data in the first place seems misguided. If there is a better way to resolve the array data at the time the data becomes available, I'm interested.

Comment: This is doomed to fail because, if the source is an `object`, the receiver has no way of operating on a custom type of your choosing if they don't already know exactly what type they want to cast to. Notably, you can't cast a value in an `object` to `int` if it isn't already an `int` -- your conversion operators won't be considered in this case. You can't have something that will operate exactly as an `int`, but is lazy -- if you need this, explicitly make it lazy and make the receivers aware of it (i.e. use `Contract` or `Lazy` consistently and don't mix it with plain scalars).

Comment: You can get around some of the restrictions of static typing if you make all the values `dynamic` (possibly with your own `DynamicObject`), but that has its own caveats and can introduce other problems. Nevertheless, if you really wanted to hide the lazy evaluation that would be one way.

Comment: The difficulty is that when the client code comes to evaluate the contents of the array, it expects an integer but finds a boxed value. If it was dynamic, it would still encounter a Contract object rather than the int it expects. I overloaded the int cast operator in hopes that it would perform a cast to the type it expects, but it does not. I really need some way of either a) automatically unboxing the type when the client code evaluates it or b) manually unboxing the type myself just beforehand.

Comment: This is not possible because the runtime does not allow you to override or customize boxing conversions (if it had to make provisions for this, it would have a massive negative impact on performance). If you can inject code that performs the conversion, it's fine -- you can just use `is`, `.GetType().Equals()` and `Enumerable.Select` to make a new sequence where you turn all the `Contract`s back into scalars again. Give `Contract` a `.Value` property for this, that's much more convenient than conversion operators.

Comment: Maybe populate the array with `Nullable<T>`, which would initially be `.HasValue==false` for all elements, then fill in the `.Value` properties as they become available?

Comment: Seems like you need `Lazy<T>` or `Task<T>` from `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (depending on whether it's more "push" or "pull" oriented for when the computation occurs), but the consumer *has* to be in on the secret.

Comment: The client code doesn't work with Nullable types, it can't use boxed values.
@Damien_The_Unbeliever Unfortunately I have no control over the code that uses the object[]. I can only prepare the array with the types it expects beforehand. Lazy<T> definitely looks like it's made for this use case, assuming I had control over the consumer.

Comment: `dynamic` is still an option, because `dynamic` conversions happen at runtime. You can have a `DynamicObject` that can be cast to an `int` even if it is not actually an `int`. However, such things tend to be too clever by half because they abstract away an essential difference in behavior that consumers should *want* to know. I recommend rethinking your approach entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed direction a little and now have a workable solution.

```
// First, got rid of the complicated generic and interface
public class Contract
{
    // The target array to modify
    public object[] Target { get; set; }
    // Index to the item in the target array
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public void Resolve()
    {
        // Change the value stored in the target array from Contract to int
        Target[Index] = 0;
    }
}

List<Contract> Contracts = new List<Contract>();

// Expected types: string, int, DateTime
object[] Items = new object[] { 
    "hello", new Contract(), DateTime.Now()
}

// A preprocessing step for Items array
foreach (var Item in Items)
{
    if (Item is Contract)
    {
        var Contract = (Contract)Item;
        Contract.Index = Index;
        Contract.Target = Items;
        Contracts.Add(Contract);
    }
}

// Later
foreach(var Contract in Contracts)
{
    Contract.Resolve();
}
```

The pre-processing step for Items is the main overhead that results from the change. The rest is simplified. The real implementation is a little more complex and has more detailed requirements than shown here. This shows the key concepts for reaching the solution. Thank you to commenters for your assistance.